# SQLite - Help optimizing aggregate total of previous rows with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to get conditional SUMs of the Value column for each record in the table for all of the "previous" records grouped by the same "Category" field value, and the same "Approved" field value, then divided into Negative and Positive sums.

In my program, users can create document record in any order, so "previous" is defined as:

If *Approved*=TRUE, then "previous" records have an older *ApprovedDate* field value than the current record. If the *ApprovedDate* field values are the same, then "previous" records have a lower *DocumentNumber* field value.

If *Approved*=FALSE, then "previous" records have an older *IssuedDate* field value than the current record. If the *IssuedDate* field values are the same, then the "previous" records have a lower *DocumentNumber* field value.

For example, in the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Changes (GUID TEXT, Value REAL, DocumentNumber TEXT, Approved INTEGER, ApprovedDate TEXT, IssuedDate TEXT, Category TEXT);
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('4F7253A4E1B3D841B84D4A82B4F0E7A2', '11', 0, 18526.7, '', '2009-03-31T05:00:00Z', 'UNKNOWN');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('D97537852E927B499C21C14F3D13CF06', '1', 0, 0, '', '2008-11-10T05:00:00Z', 'UNKNOWN');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('857DADB463807345918729B33399B36F', '2', 0, 0, '', '2008-11-10T05:00:00Z', 'UNKNOWN');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('7989D242E05AFF4FB5EE99114822BF80', '21', 0, 50112, '', '2009-07-22T05:00:00Z', 'UNKNOWN');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('16A0AB27FD3A784D9E0A14406C7683E0', '3', 0, 0, '', '2009-01-15T05:00:00Z', 'UNKNOWN');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('D3D7B1C306D38C438FC3DEDFCB57D411', '131', 0, 17204, '', '2010-12-14T05:00:00Z', 'UNKNOWN');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('2C89D974DDF86743A0D7D62B385FBDEF', '147', 0, 0, '', '2010-12-01T05:00:00Z', 'UNKNOWN');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('F371D4237C837D448824697EB0162905', '198', 0, 0, '', '2011-01-10T05:00:00Z', 'UNKNOWN');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('433D64C871AE4E46A0E1BFCE2BB69BA7', '364', 0, 0, '', '2011-11-14T05:00:00Z', 'UNKNOWN');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('808496DBDE76CB4F911396BB817724F3', '352', 0, 0, '', '2011-10-17T05:00:00Z', 'UNKNOWN');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('9545DEF1666B5F4D8626F19F8E9E9333', '418', 0, 10948, '', '2012-03-07T22:19:18Z', 'UNKNOWN');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('244D7D89B79E0F4E91100E4ADB300656', '439', 0, 50945, '', '2012-04-27T20:33:26Z', 'UNKNOWN');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('115A427BBB1D2C43BA11D9E5875FAA2C', '465', 0, 480049, '', '2012-07-20T16:17:54Z', 'UNKNOWN');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('3A2271EFCC767E4CA40017E68802F10C', '478', 0, 54298, '', '2012-08-01T17:26:38Z', 'UNKNOWN');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('99D0EFC5A9F1AA498DB1A4CDF294129B', '490', 0, 11500, '', '2012-09-18T14:23:13Z', 'ALTER');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('38B2E3A379C5084998E6A84D496AC555', '491', 0, 26088, '', '2012-09-25T06:00:00Z', 'ALTER');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('8902831C8FAD4941841EE2847656BDAF', '494', 0, -825, '', '2012-10-16T14:20:06Z', 'ALTER');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('7AFDB08A002AE54A8DE7699855AEBE30', '495', 0, 221, '', '2012-10-16T14:21:27Z', 'ALTER');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('38A2CCEF5F0B294AA8B8752F461D121D', '496', 0, 0, '', '2012-12-24T01:11:15Z', 'ALTER');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('24CCD5CE409E674593108CBD816DBCCE', '486', 1, -825, '2012-10-01T21:42:52Z', '2012-09-17T20:42:12Z', 'ALTER');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('C7458704E36C8F448C1F3A485EB08304', '485', 1, 10000, '2012-10-01T21:25:56Z', '2012-09-11T21:29:44Z', 'ALTER');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('B511953AE6FB6446A63AA83C159057BE', '487', 1, 82170, '2012-10-01T21:42:51Z', '2012-09-17T20:46:41Z', 'ALTER');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('EC977BC304A971439D04BB9DF4D8188A', '488', 1, 15500, '2012-10-01T20:58:15Z', '2012-09-18T06:00:00Z', 'ALTER');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('D9B1F0C0A8E490448697B783639E09E0', '489', 1, 11503, '2012-10-01T21:42:50Z', '2012-09-18T13:56:18Z', 'ALTER');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('698BB6D65832D146A49727C717A591A1', '492', 1, 2787, '2012-10-01T21:10:06Z', '2012-09-25T15:55:02Z', 'ALTER');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('155D4F2B1854B34FABCDE8CF20F1E44C', '493', 1, 12162, '2012-10-01T21:10:06Z', '2012-09-25T16:04:40Z', 'ALTER');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('137C9BF2B1EFD34B8831ADA70C5F9431', '1', 1, 369543, '2011-12-08T13:41:04Z', '1899-12-30T05:00:00Z', 'DRAW');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('7F29FC7114BD10468AE92A047345B5DB', '2', 1, 7258, '2011-12-08T13:41:04Z', '2011-10-20T05:00:00Z', 'DRAW');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('6B66D8EAD88E6E4FA29401CD524B978A', '3', 1, 979321, '2011-12-08T13:41:04Z', '2011-11-08T05:00:00Z', 'DRAW');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('7F393B712B213041A6DD211E04F6DCA6', '4', 1, 14998, '2012-04-20T15:16:21Z', '2012-04-18T21:07:07Z', 'DRAW');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('2255F84E7C7DA04389765724872D6413', '5', 1, 58926, '2012-04-20T15:16:23Z', '2012-04-18T21:13:15Z', 'DRAW');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('DB4A5588DEB9F34C868F7AD1CB13ACC3', '6', 1, 13232, '2012-04-20T15:16:05Z', '2012-04-18T21:17:00Z', 'DRAW');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('B5231AE40F8E7D41BA0A4D09614CBDF9', '7', 1, 10176, '2012-04-20T15:16:25Z', '2012-04-18T21:19:41Z', 'DRAW');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('2362D54FCC53E447AC7D8289EA89FD05', '8', 1, 17556, '2012-04-20T15:16:04Z', '2012-04-18T21:21:20Z', 'DRAW');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('6ED4565CA041704B8D006EDA4A1E4CF9', '9', 1, 399639, '2012-05-30T16:32:43Z', '2012-05-17T06:00:00Z', 'DRAW');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('B21BE07E3E42C2418C70AD17862D3AE1', '10', 1, 6231, '2012-08-16T16:55:00Z', '2012-08-02T16:02:03Z', 'DRAW');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('8FD252A50137754A98698F93AC9B01A7', '11', 1, 629, '2012-08-16T16:54:58Z', '2012-08-02T16:07:57Z', 'DRAW');
INSERT INTO Changes (GUID, DocumentNumber, Approved, Value, ApprovedDate, IssuedDate, Category) VALUES ('1B9AFD2C20362F48A486E8A535B29AF5', '20', 1, -113810, '2011-12-13T17:15:53Z', '2010-02-10T05:00:00Z', 'UNKNOWN');
```

The results should be:

**[Results][2]**:

```
|                             GUID |                             SORTID |          VALUE | POSITIVE_PREVIOUS_TOTAL | NEGATIVE_PREVIOUS_TOTAL |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 99D0EFC5A9F1AA498DB1A4CDF294129B |   ALTER_0_2012-09-18T14:23:13Z_490 |          11500 |                       0 |                       0 |
| 38B2E3A379C5084998E6A84D496AC555 |   ALTER_0_2012-09-25T06:00:00Z_491 |          26088 |                   11500 |                       0 |
| 8902831C8FAD4941841EE2847656BDAF |   ALTER_0_2012-10-16T14:20:06Z_494 |           -825 |                   37588 |                       0 |
| 7AFDB08A002AE54A8DE7699855AEBE30 |   ALTER_0_2012-10-16T14:21:27Z_495 |            221 |                   37588 |                    -825 |
| 38A2CCEF5F0B294AA8B8752F461D121D |   ALTER_0_2012-12-24T01:11:15Z_496 |              0 |                   37809 |                    -825 |
| EC977BC304A971439D04BB9DF4D8188A |   ALTER_1_2012-10-01T20:58:15Z_488 |          15500 |                   92170 |                    -825 |
| 698BB6D65832D146A49727C717A591A1 |   ALTER_1_2012-10-01T21:10:06Z_492 |           2787 |                  119173 |                    -825 |
| 155D4F2B1854B34FABCDE8CF20F1E44C |   ALTER_1_2012-10-01T21:10:06Z_493 |          12162 |                  121960 |                    -825 |
| C7458704E36C8F448C1F3A485EB08304 |   ALTER_1_2012-10-01T21:25:56Z_485 |          10000 |                       0 |                       0 |
| D9B1F0C0A8E490448697B783639E09E0 |   ALTER_1_2012-10-01T21:42:50Z_489 |          11503 |                  107670 |                    -825 |
| B511953AE6FB6446A63AA83C159057BE |   ALTER_1_2012-10-01T21:42:51Z_487 |          82170 |                   10000 |                    -825 |
| 24CCD5CE409E674593108CBD816DBCCE |   ALTER_1_2012-10-01T21:42:52Z_486 |           -825 |                   10000 |                       0 |
| 137C9BF2B1EFD34B8831ADA70C5F9431 |      DRAW_1_2011-12-08T13:41:04Z_1 |         369543 |                       0 |                       0 |
| 7F29FC7114BD10468AE92A047345B5DB |      DRAW_1_2011-12-08T13:41:04Z_2 |           7258 |                  369543 |                       0 |
| 6B66D8EAD88E6E4FA29401CD524B978A |      DRAW_1_2011-12-08T13:41:04Z_3 |         979321 |                  376801 |                       0 |
| 2362D54FCC53E447AC7D8289EA89FD05 |      DRAW_1_2012-04-20T15:16:04Z_8 |          17556 |                 1453454 |                       0 |
| DB4A5588DEB9F34C868F7AD1CB13ACC3 |      DRAW_1_2012-04-20T15:16:05Z_6 |          13232 |                 1430046 |                       0 |
| 7F393B712B213041A6DD211E04F6DCA6 |      DRAW_1_2012-04-20T15:16:21Z_4 |          14998 |                 1356122 |                       0 |
| 2255F84E7C7DA04389765724872D6413 |      DRAW_1_2012-04-20T15:16:23Z_5 |          58926 |                 1371120 |                       0 |
| B5231AE40F8E7D41BA0A4D09614CBDF9 |      DRAW_1_2012-04-20T15:16:25Z_7 |          10176 |                 1443278 |                       0 |
| 6ED4565CA041704B8D006EDA4A1E4CF9 |      DRAW_1_2012-05-30T16:32:43Z_9 |         399639 |                 1471010 |                       0 |
| 8FD252A50137754A98698F93AC9B01A7 |     DRAW_1_2012-08-16T16:54:58Z_11 |            629 |                 1876880 |                       0 |
| B21BE07E3E42C2418C70AD17862D3AE1 |     DRAW_1_2012-08-16T16:55:00Z_10 |           6231 |                 1870649 |                       0 |
| D97537852E927B499C21C14F3D13CF06 |   UNKNOWN_0_2008-11-10T05:00:00Z_1 |              0 |                       0 |                       0 |
| 857DADB463807345918729B33399B36F |   UNKNOWN_0_2008-11-10T05:00:00Z_2 |              0 |                       0 |                       0 |
| 16A0AB27FD3A784D9E0A14406C7683E0 |   UNKNOWN_0_2009-01-15T05:00:00Z_3 |              0 |                       0 |                       0 |
| 4F7253A4E1B3D841B84D4A82B4F0E7A2 |  UNKNOWN_0_2009-03-31T05:00:00Z_11 | 18526.69921875 |                       0 |                       0 |
| 7989D242E05AFF4FB5EE99114822BF80 |  UNKNOWN_0_2009-07-22T05:00:00Z_21 |          50112 |          18526.69921875 |                       0 |
| 2C89D974DDF86743A0D7D62B385FBDEF | UNKNOWN_0_2010-12-01T05:00:00Z_147 |              0 |          68638.69921875 |                       0 |
| D3D7B1C306D38C438FC3DEDFCB57D411 | UNKNOWN_0_2010-12-14T05:00:00Z_131 |          17204 |          68638.69921875 |                       0 |
| F371D4237C837D448824697EB0162905 | UNKNOWN_0_2011-01-10T05:00:00Z_198 |              0 |          85842.69921875 |                       0 |
| 808496DBDE76CB4F911396BB817724F3 | UNKNOWN_0_2011-10-17T05:00:00Z_352 |              0 |          85842.69921875 |                       0 |
| 433D64C871AE4E46A0E1BFCE2BB69BA7 | UNKNOWN_0_2011-11-14T05:00:00Z_364 |              0 |          85842.69921875 |                       0 |
| 9545DEF1666B5F4D8626F19F8E9E9333 | UNKNOWN_0_2012-03-07T22:19:18Z_418 |          10948 |          85842.69921875 |                       0 |
| 244D7D89B79E0F4E91100E4ADB300656 | UNKNOWN_0_2012-04-27T20:33:26Z_439 |          50945 |          96790.69921875 |                       0 |
| 115A427BBB1D2C43BA11D9E5875FAA2C | UNKNOWN_0_2012-07-20T16:17:54Z_465 |         480049 |         147735.69921875 |                       0 |
| 3A2271EFCC767E4CA40017E68802F10C | UNKNOWN_0_2012-08-01T17:26:38Z_478 |          54298 |         627784.69921875 |                       0 |
| 1B9AFD2C20362F48A486E8A535B29AF5 |  UNKNOWN_1_2011-12-13T17:15:53Z_20 |        -113810 |                       0 |                       0 |
```

Essentially - all records are group by the Category and Approved field values, then sorted by the Approved Date, DocumentNumber (if Approved=TRUE), or the IssuedDate, DocumentNumber (if Approved=FALSE). Finally a running sum on a record-by-record basis is tallied for the value of each previous record with the same category and approved value, with negative sums and positive sums reported in separate columns.

I can get the desired results with sub-selects, but the performance is poor (700-ish records takes 6.5 seconds). I've been trying to use CASE WHEN statements combined with various GROUP BY and HAVING clauses, but I can't seem to get the correct values (I can't get the logic to determine the "previous" records to meet my requirements). However, using this approach the performance is very good (less than 200ms in most cases for the same data set).

Here's my attempt that works (SQLite only, T-SQL below), but takes a long time:

```
SELECT a.GUID, 
SUM(CASE WHEN b.Value>0 THEN b.Value ELSE 0 END) as positive_previous_total, 
SUM(CASE WHEN b.Value<0 THEN b.Value ELSE 0 END)  as negative_previous_total 
FROM Changes AS a left join Changes as b 
ON b.rowid != a.rowid 
AND b.Approved =a.Approved 
AND b.Category=a.Category 
AND ((IFNULL(SUBSTR(CASE WHEN b.Approved THEN b.ApprovedDate ELSE b.IssuedDate END, 1, 10), '0000-00-00')<IFNULL(SUBSTR(CASE WHEN a.Approved THEN a.ApprovedDate ELSE a.IssuedDate END, 1, 10), '0000-00-00') 
OR ((IFNULL(SUBSTR(CASE WHEN b.Approved THEN b.ApprovedDate ELSE b.IssuedDate END, 1, 10), '0000-00-00')=IFNULL(SUBSTR(CASE WHEN a.Approved THEN a.ApprovedDate ELSE a.IssuedDate END, 1, 10), '0000-00-00') AND b.DocumentNumber<a.DocumentNumber)))) 
GROUP BY a.rowid
```

Here's my attempt that works (T-SQL)

```
   SELECT 
    a.[GUID], 
    [positive_previous_total] = SUM(CASE WHEN b.Value>0 THEN b.Value ELSE 0 END), 
    [negative_previous_total] = SUM(CASE WHEN b.Value<0 THEN b.Value ELSE 0 END) 
FROM 
    #Changes a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #Changes b 
        ON 
        b.[GUID]    <> a.[GUID] AND
        b.Approved  = a.Approved AND
        b.Category  = a.Category 
        AND 
        (
        ISNULL(SUBSTRING(CASE WHEN b.Approved=1 THEN b.ApprovedDate ELSE b.IssuedDate END, 1, 10), '0000-00-00') 
          < ISNULL(SUBSTRING(CASE WHEN a.Approved=1 THEN a.ApprovedDate ELSE a.IssuedDate END, 1, 10), '0000-00-00')
        OR 
            (
            ISNULL(SUBSTRING(CASE WHEN b.Approved=1 THEN b.ApprovedDate ELSE b.IssuedDate END, 1, 10), '0000-00-00')
              =ISNULL(SUBSTRING(CASE WHEN a.Approved=1 THEN a.ApprovedDate ELSE a.IssuedDate END, 1, 10), '0000-00-00') 
            AND 
            b.DocumentNumber<a.DocumentNumber
            )
        ) 
GROUP BY a.[GUID]
```

Does anybody have any suggestions for getting the results I need more optimally?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Turns out my computer was in "power saver" mode, which was really slowing down the query. It now takes about 1.5 seconds after switching to Maximum Performance, which is OK, but any optimization tips are still very welcome.

Comment: doesn't run for me - I get the error `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'.`....maybe it should be `...CASE WHEN a.Approved = 1...`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply whytheq - I've had to manually transcribe MySql syntax from SQLFiddle to SQLite, so I may have made a mistake - I'm reviewing it now and I will fix any problems.

Comment: ok - sqllite is T-sql? so it should work on my 2008-R2. It is also not recognizing `IFNULL` - maybe you need to use `ISNULL` - and also SUBSTR will need replacing with some sql-server text functions

Comment: Perhaps IFNULL is an SQLite only extension? The function returns the first NON-Null value of 2 parameters (it's a 2-param COALESCE, if that is a T-SQL function?)

Comment: I've changed the query to use Approved=1, although SQLite seems to manually coerce the value to Boolean when comparing so it is unnecessary in SQLite (there is no BOOLEAN type in SQLite, just INTEGER for boolean values).

Comment: Hi whytheq - I've added a query near the bottom that I think should work in pure T-SQL.

Comment: it's almost instantaneous on my machine !!

Comment: It is near instantaneous for me with only the 30ish records listed in my example, but it takes about 1.5 seconds with my full 700ish record data set. It's useable in my scenario, but not great (I'd prefer to get it to under 500ms if possible). Thanks again for looking into it!

Comment: I'm struggling to optimize. I made the query more readable to see if I could see anything obvious. If nothing else I've edited the OP with a prettier version of the query;

Comment: I've created a simpler question for you on [SO HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073190/can-this-be-simplified-and-therefore-optimized)

Comment: It might be the best that can be done - maybe SQLite doesn't optimize the query very well by short-circuiting on early FALSE conditions, while 2008-R2 might perform better in this regard. In any case, I appreciate the attempt and re-format, thanks a lot.

Comment: Feeling guilty for my lack of help so I've created a simpler question for you on [SO HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073190/can-this-be-simplified-and-therefore-optimized)

Comment: No need to feel guilty, I appreciate what you've done. I see the thread on SO HERE is focusing a lot on the underlying table schema, which unfortunately I don't have control over, so there are no optimizations to be had there. I've also got indexes on all of the applicable columns, so there's either a query logic optimization or bust.

Comment: what indexes do you have on the table `Changes` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to suggestions [**HERE ON SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073190/can-this-be-simplified-and-therefore-optimized) for ways you can speed things up.

Two or three SO heavyweights have contributed so I'd get in touch with your DBA and see what changes can be made.

Seems the consensus is that you need to add some indexing on the `changes` table.

I also likes the idea of adding a couple of calculated fields into this table to then make the subsequent script a lot more readable.

If you are able to change some of the data types then there's lots of suggestions in the answers.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you - been busy travelling and dealing with the holidays. Thanks a lot for your help (and the ON SO help). That help, plus some other discoveries of my own (that I will post shortly) have let me get the SELECT time down to  ~640ms, which is good enough for my purposes. Happy New Year!

Comment: @JPBro which of the answers in ON SO should I mark as the answer?

Comment: Stuart Blackler's idea of using computed columns seemed to provide the most benefit (I already had indexes on all of the appropriate columns in my production DB). Post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14073566/1933425 - I had to modify things a bit for SQLite by using TRIGGERS (since it doesn't support computed columns like SQLServer), but the principle of having the groupings precomputed is the same.

Comment: I've marked @StuartBlackler as the answer; interesting double-act ....till next time happy SOverflowing!

Comment: Thanks for all of your help whytheq, I really appreciate it. It was a good first experience for me, and Happy SOverflowing to you too!

Answer (score 2):

First of all - thanks to whytheq and the contributors in the following thread: [Can this be simplified and therefore optimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073190/can-this-be-simplified-and-therefore-optimized) which is worth a read even though the solutions are not all applicable to SQLite due to its limitations. I was able to implement some optimizations based on the suggestions to cut the SELECT time in half.

How it was done:

1. Added and EffectiveDate column that stores the date portion of the ApprovedDate when Approved=TRUE, or IssuedDate when Approved=FALSE as an integer instead of as ISO8601 text.
2. Added a new column called EffectiveID that stores the Category, Approved, zero-padded EffectiveDate and zero-padded DocumentNumber as a single value for quicker comparisons.
3. Created an UPDATE TRIGGER on update of the Approved, IssuedDate and ApprovedDate columns to update the EffectiveDate column.
4. Created a UPDATE TRIGGER on the EFfectiveDate, Category, Approved, and Number columns to update the EffectiveID field accordingly.
5. Created a TRIGGER on insert of a new row to update the EffectiveDate accordingly.
6. Added INDEXes for the EffectiveDate and EffectiveID columns
7. Rearranged the ON clause tests to reduce the number of matches, reducing processing
8. Changed the JOIN to select only the required subset of columns in the result set.

The final SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT 
a.GUID, 
TOTAL(CASE WHEN b.Value>0 THEN b.Value ELSE 0 END) as positive_previous_total, 
TOTAL(CASE WHEN b.Value<0 THEN b.Value ELSE 0 END) as negative_previous_total 
FROM 
Changes AS a 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT rowid, Value, Category, Approved, EffectiveId FROM Changes) as b 
ON 
b.EffectiveID < a.EffectiveID 
AND b.Category=a.Category
AND b.Approved=a.Approved
AND b.rowid != a.rowid
GROUP BY 
a.rowid
```